# Prefill username and password input field on django admin login page

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I would like to set a default value for the username and password input fields on admin/login.html. I thought to edit the login.html template but I cannot figure out how to add  the default value to the input fields {{ form.username }} and {{ form.password }} which are coming from the database.

```
<label for="id_username" class="required">{% trans 'Username:' %}</label> {{ form.username }}
<label for="id_password" class="required">{% trans 'Password:' %}</label> {{ form.password }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people use javascript to put default values but it can be done in django-forms itself. You can use `_initial_` which is explained [here](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter07/). There are 2 ways you can put initial values as far as I know...

1. You have two options either populate the value when calling form constructor:

   `form = UserForm(initial={'username': 'please enter username', 'password':'enter password'})`
2. set the value in the form definition:

   `username = forms.CharField(initial='please enter username')`

Comment: Thank you! In order to use _initial_ I will have to write a custom view for the admin login form, correct? That is, _initial_ cannot be set in the template?

Comment: django-forms were built for this. Isn't it cleaner is all form related stuff was in one place? instead of having some part in templates & other part in django-forms. anyway, all of this is just guidelines. One can decide to follow it, bend rules, break rules, create new ones...

Answer (score -2):

Try this. All you need to do is:

```
User Name:{{ form.username }}<br>
Password:{{ form.password }}
```